# Compact operator as certain limit

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$. Let $P_n := \sum_{i=1}^n e_ie_i^*$, i.e. $P_n$ is the projection onto the span of the first $n$ basis vectors. Let $K$ be a compact operator. Then I want to prove that $P_nK \to K$ in operator norm.

I want to stick to the definition that an operator is compact if it is a limit of finite rank operators. I think it is necassary to use the fact that there are finite rank operators $K_n$ with $K_n \to K$, but I could not use it properly.

Comment: It is hard to recognize a question here.

Comment: Okay, the question is why $P_nK \to K$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of one approach:

Proving that $P_n K \to K$ in operator norm is equivalent to proving that $K - P_n K = (I - P_n)K \to 0$ in operator norm. If your definition of $K$ being compact is that it is a operator norm limit of finite-rank operators, then let $K_j$ be the sequence of finite-rank operators converging to $K$. Then
$$ (I - P_n)K = (I- P_n)(K-K_j) + (I - P_n)K_j  $$
Given an $\epsilon$, we need to find $N$ so that the above expression is less than $\epsilon$ in operator norm for all $n \geq N$ (we are free to choose $j$ as we please).

Make the first term small by choosing $j$ to be large, and note that $||I-P_n|| = 1$ for all $n$.

After we've chosen a $j$, we could estimate the second term by writing $K_j$ as a finite sum of rank-one maps, and prove directly that $I-P_n$ composed with a rank-one map is small in operator norm for large $n$.

I think that should do the trick. Can you fill in the details?