# Equivalence Operator Compact in Hilbert Space with Projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> let $H$ a hilbert space, 
>   $\{e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ an orthonormal basis for $H$, and $\operatorname{A}\in B(H)$
>
> $\forall n\geqslant  0$ , $\operatorname{E_{n}}$ is the projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{e_{1},....,e_{n}\}$
>
> $\operatorname{A}$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left \| (\operatorname{Id}-\operatorname{E}_{n})\operatorname{A}(\operatorname{Id}-\operatorname{E_{n}}) \right \|=0$

any idea, or book where i can read this

i think forward direction $\Rightarrow$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138861/compact-operator-as-certain-limit)

thanks

Edit:

> i was thinking and
>
> $\| (\operatorname{Id}-\operatorname{E}_{n})\operatorname{A}(\operatorname{Id}-\operatorname{E_{n}}) \| = \| \operatorname{A}-\operatorname{AE_{n}} -\operatorname{E_{n} A}+\operatorname{E_{n} A E_{n}} \| $
>
> and
>
> $-\operatorname{AE_{n}} +\operatorname{E_{n} A}-\operatorname{E_{n} A E_{n}}$
>
> are sum of three finite's rank operator, so are compact $\forall n\geqslant  0$
>
> so $A$ is compact for be limit of compact's  operator
>   .

other way for forward direction $\Rightarrow$

> using that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||A(e_n)||= 0$
>   , i can go to
>
> $||A(Id-E_{k})||=\delta \cdot sup_{||x||\leqslant 1} \sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}|<x,e_{j}> |$
>
> where k is the natural for $||A(e_{j})||<\delta$,  $\forall j>k$

but how delimit sumatory?

Comment: looks good.........

Comment: This result is quite standard and can for example be found in the book "Compact Non-Self-Adjoint Operators" by J.R.Ringrose (Theorem 1.8.7).

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde: My guess it that this is an exercise. The fact that this is a standard result is not really helpful in this case.

Comment: @tomasz Might be, then again OP merely asked for "any idea, or book where i can read this" (at least at the time when I first came here) and I gave a reference where an exact proof is given they can read up on.

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde: You're right. I missed that part. Sorry!